# Java Input String into Time

Tags: java

How can I make a Java program so that, in a console application, if the user were to enter a time (say 13:00) as a String with the Scanner, I can turn this String into a time object that can be used for maths.

Any ideas or am I in way over my head?

Edit:

In my app, charges apply for different times (extra for night time etc). I need to be able to get the numbers from a String (or Double, I'm flexible)

Comment: Use [SimpleDataFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object

Comment: Could you please be specific about the `Time` object you are referring to?

Comment: In my app, charges apply for different times (extra for night time etc). I need to be able to get the numbers from a String (or Double, I'm flexible)

Comment: @TashM You can edit your question. That way you don't have to explain your goal in the comments. Comments are supposed to be temporarely, try to put the info in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a couple of things first, like giving a hint to the user about how the input time can look like... So I would do:

1. Define the input format for the time
2. Give a hint to the user about it
3. Parse the input to the format you defined
4. And finally manipulate the date as you need it

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String format = "HH:mm:ss";
    System.out.println("Please give the desired time in this fomrat HH:mm:ss ...");
    String inp = s.nextLine();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(inp);
        System.out.println("this is the date:" + date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println("invalid date...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, how can I then use this to work with a while loop to do a specific task between certain times (eg with pseudo code: while time > 05:00 && time < 16:59)?

Comment: yes for sure... can you open a new question and add some words about what exactly you want/need? :)