# Java While Loop With Time

Tags: java, string, time, while-loop

How can I use [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37894707/6482242) to work with a while loop to do a specific task between certain times (eg with pseudo code:

`while time > 05:00 && time < 16:59`

I understand that I need to change these to ints after the input, I'm just not sure how to do the actual while loop.

I've changed them to ints in the following way:

```
String hoursString = time.substring(0,1);
String minutesString = time.substring(3,4);

int hours = Integer.parseInt(hoursString);

int minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutesString);
```

Edit:

Thank you all so much for your help, I went with another direction of if statements that check the less than and more than conditions of the time. :)

```
if ((hours >= 05) && (hours <= 16) { do stuff}
```

That's what I went with. ^

Comment: In Java, while take an expression. So you can't use greater than.

Comment: I think in java parentheses are needed around the expression that while uses as conditional whatever. Could you edit the question to add, how you used this with hours and minutes you calculated? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the dates until the condition is met...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String format = TIME_FORMAT;
boolean isDateOk = false;
Date theDate1 = new Date();
Date theDate2 = new Date();
try {
    theDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT).parse("05:00");
    theDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT).parse("16:59");
} catch (ParseException e1) {
}
String inp = "";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
while (!isDateOk) {
    System.out.println("Please give the desired time in this fomrat HH:mm ...");
    inp = s.nextLine();
    try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(inp);
    if (date.compareTo(theDate1) > 0 && date.compareTo(theDate2) < 0) {
        isDateOk = true;
    }
    // date.compareTo(theDate1) // will return an int, if negative
    // means date time is bigger than theDate1
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    System.err.println("invalid date...");
    }
}
// out of the while
System.out.println("the given date was ok");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Timer

You wouldn't want to use a while loop.  A while loop will lock up your UI.  What you should do instead is use a [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) .

Basically, you'd want to do this as found in this post [Scheduling a Timer Task to Run at a Certain Time : Timer](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/SchedulingaTimerTasktoRunataCertainTime.htm):

```
   import java.sql.Date; import java.util.Timer; import 
  java.util.TimerTask;

        public class Main {   public static void main(String[] argv) throws
         Exception {

             Date timeToRun = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + numberOfMillisecondsInTheFuture);


              Timer timer = new Timer();

                  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                      System.out.println("doing");
                   }
                  }, timeToRun);   } }
```

Then you would just end the timer at your end time.  Of course, in your particular case, you would just initialize the date object with the specific date you want instead of using a certain number of milliseconds in the future.

Comment: While a `Timer` is a good way to learn, as that [class’s documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) mentions you should graduate to using an [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), specifically a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Search Stack Overflow for much more info.